# Sealing yet another gap between basements

Tags: hvac, seal

I found a large gap in the wall above a HVAC duct (picture below). This wall is between the basement in the original house and the basement under the (circa ~2001) addition. The former owner had stuffed the space with fiberglass insulation, which had a mouse nest in it.

I will re-route that wire (there's a conduit elsewhere that all the other wires go through, guess someone got lazy with this one), but what is a good method of sealing this open space? It is big enough that I would normally put some bricks there to fill it - but they'd be sitting directly on top of the HVAC duct, which doesn't seem right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the fiberglass material again to fill the gap but leave a 2" - 3" deep (into the wall) grove to be filled with mortar. This will cut off the mouse traffic path, or nesting in the gap. You might have to re-do it at a later date though.